# I think there is an error in this website which calculates a confidence interval for Variance

Tags: probability, statistics

Please consider the following website:

```
 http://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/06evar.html
```

In this website, they calculate s to be about $0.391868$ but in the calculations
they use $0.391868$ for the value of $s^2$. Therefore, I feel they are wrong but I am not sure. Therefore, I am hoping somebody could either confirm that I am wrong or tell me where I went wrong.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. If

$$x = \begin{bmatrix}6.0&6.4&7.0&5.8&6.0&5.8&5.9&6.7&6.1&6.5&6.3&5.8\end{bmatrix} $$
then $n=12$ and
\begin{align}
\bar x &= \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 6.1916666667\\
s^2 &= \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2 = 0.1535606061\\
s &= \sqrt{s^2} = 0.3918680978
\end{align}
Where they have "Value of $s^2$" instead has the value of $s$. So the $95\%$ confidence interval ($\alpha=0.05$) for $\sigma^2$ would be given by
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{n-1,1-\alpha/2}}, \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{n-1,\alpha/2}}\right) &= \left(\frac{(12-1)0.1535606061}{21.92004926}, \frac{(12-1)0.1535606061}{3.815748252} \right)\\
&= (0.07706034994, 0.4426829432)
\end{align}
and the $95\%$ confidence interval for $\sigma$
$$(\sqrt{0.07706034994}, \sqrt{0.4426829432}) = (0.2775974602,0.6653442291). $$

Answer (score 1):

Comment:  In R statistical software the computations are as follows.

```
 x = c(6.0, 6.4, 7.0, 5.8, 6.0, 5.8, 5.9, 6.7, 6.1, 6.5, 6.3, 5.8)
 n = length(x);  v = var(x);  s = sd(x);  n;  v;  s
 ## 12              # sample size
 ## 0.1535606       # sample variance
 ## 0.3918681       # sample standard deviation

 ci.var = (n-1)*v/qchisq(c(.975,.025), n-1);  ci.var
 ## 0.07706035 0.44268294       # 95% CI for pop variance
 ci.sd = sqrt(ci.var);  ci.sd
 ## 0.2775975 0.6653442         # 95% CI for pop SD
```

The computation is based on the fact that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim Chisq(n - 1).$ First, we find a CI for $\sigma^2$.
Then if a CI for $\sigma$ is required, take square roots of
the endpoints of the CI for $\sigma^2,$ as in the fine Answer by @Math1000.

Unfortunately, it seems to be a frequent mistake in
textbooks and software manuals to confuse the sample
variance $S^2$ and the sample standard deviation $S,$
and it seems you have found an example. (There is no excuse for such mistakes, but I am sympathetic. I just
repaired this kind of error in one of my other posts on this site an
hour ago.)